# Don't show ad for Developer Survey if you've already taken it

Tags: feature-request, advertising, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I just noticed an advertisement for the Developer Survey 2020:

[image]

I have already taken it two weeks ago, and the system knows about this since it awarded me a [badge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/204/census?userid=223536) for it. In that case, it's better to reserve valuable advertising space for paying customers (as long as they provide on-topic, non-annoying and non-privacy-attacking ads, but that's another story), and it prevents people from accidentally filling it in twice.

Comment: Given they use an 3rd party ad service, wouldn't that mean they have to provide them with your collected badges and by doing so won't they breach their own privacy policy? This doesn't feel like a good idea, at all.

Comment: I'm sure they can figure something out which doesn't breach the privacy policy. Whether it's too difficult to implement, I don't know...

Comment: will be fixed tomorrow. :)

Comment: Also the "[Last Chance] Take the 2020 Developer Survey before it closes" email seemed unnecessary.